# Two player have flush

Tags: flush

Hi when tow player have flush whish one win the game
When the highest card is at the desk
For exam:
P1:5w 7w
P2:7w 8w
At desk:kw 10w 3w 2x 6x
Thanks

Comment: Not sure what 7w is but if tow players have it then you have a bad deck.  The hand will be killed.  It is called a board.